# UnboundLocalError, Python

Tags: python

estoy realizando un código , y me he encontrado con este error en mi función  la cual pertenece a la dentención de movimiento de un "coche" que se desplaza en una matriz. Por tanto si está vacia , `" "` , se podrá desplazar pero si se encuentra con un marco `|` debería cancelar el movimiento.. dentro de este marco esta este icono utf-8 `▓`, y por tanto si lo toca debería retornar que "has ganado" , os dejo un ejemplo del tablero del cual hablo :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
def comprueba(t,orientacion,corx,cory,letramov,longitud):
    copia = copy.deepcopy(t)
    anchura = corx + longitud
    if orientacion == 'H':
        if letramov <= ord('Z'):
            comprueba = corx-1
        elif letramov >=ord('a'):
            comprueba = anchura+1
        if comprueba >19:
            retornocomprueba = 0
        else:
            valor = copia[cory][comprueba]

    elif orientacion == 'V':
        if letramov <= ord('Z'):
            comprueba = cory -1
        elif letramov >= ord('a'):
            comprueba = longitud+cory+1
        if comprueba >19:
            retornocomprueba = 0
        else:
            valor = copia[comprueba][corx]

    if valor == u'\u2593' and letramov == 'a':
        retornocomprueba = 2
    else :
        if valor != ' ':
            retornocomprueba = 0
        else:
            retornocomprueba = 1
    return retornocomprueba
```

¿Alguna solución?

**Error:**

```
juega(nvles,puntuaciones)
```

> File "C:\Users\saul\workspace\prueba\practica.py", line 241, in juega
>      if comprueba(t,orientacion,corx,cory,letramov,longitud) == 1:
>   File "C:\Users\saul\workspace\prueba\practica.py", line 130, in comprueba
>      if valor == u'\u2593' and letramov == 'a':
>   UnboundLocalError: local variable 'valor' referenced before assignment

Comment: El error dice que primero intentas usar la variable `valor` antes de asignarla o declararla. Como no tiene un valor asignado, no tiene con que comparar. No es un parámetro de tu función y tampoco está inicializad, de ahí el error.

Comment: Como dice toledano intentas hacer uso de una variable antes de asignarla. Simplemente si no se ha entrado en alguno de los `else` anteriores donde se define `valor` (porque el `if `anterior a ese `else` cumpla la condición) `valor` no existe cuando llega a  `if valor == u'\u2593' and letramov == 'a':` Es decir si `comprueba >19` no se crea la variable `valor`, al no existir no puedes hacer referencia a ella como el propio error muestra. Deberias replantearte la lógica de tu código porque algo falla. ¿Cual debería ser el contenido de `valor` si `comprueba > 19`?

Comment: Seguiré probando , a ver si consigo sacarle solución.. llevo ya todo el día y la verdad que no se me ocurre nada..

Comment: Seria más fácil ayudarte si explicaras que es cada variable o pusieras un ejemplo funcional del codigo. Tal y como está solo podemos decirte por qué se produce el error. Añade código o explicación de que es cada variable. Repito que tal y como está si la variable `comprueba` es mayor de 19 te da error porque `valor` no existe, ¿en este supuesto `valor` que debe almacenar?.

Comment: Bueno finalmente he terminado solucionandolo , como bien decías los problemas venían por ahí por tanto , para ese caso se aplica un valor con el cual va a retornar 0 la función , por ejemplo valor = 0 .. Se me olvidó decirlo , ya que se me ocurrió después de postear lo anterior. Gracias!

Comment: Aunque parece que ya has solucionado el problema, no puedo dejar pasar la oportunidad de recomendar esta charla de la PyConES 2016 que trata sobre el tema de los UnboundLocalError: **Los closures que emocionaron a Spielberg (Víctor Terrón & Pablo Salgado, 2016)** - [Vídeo [ES]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrL3CQNOFRc)
- [Diapositivas [EN]](https://github.com/vterron/PyConES-2016)